How to figure out why (isolated) USB hub IC fails to be enumerated
I am having some issues getting the USB hub IC to work on my board. The board houses a Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 (CM4) and is largely based on the CMIO4 board just with some modifications.
The issue is with an isolated USB hub, connected like so (part numbers & schematic below):
CM4 --> Hub[1] --> USB Isolator --> Hub[2]

The first hub is enumerated properly:
> lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) USB 2.0 Hub
> 

The second hub doesn't work though:
> dmesg
....
[  177.072785] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci-hcd
[  179.191205] usb 1-1-port1: attempt power cycle
[  181.215197] usb 1-1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
> 

It seems that some kind of communication is making its way through the isolator chip: When triggering a reset using sudo usbreset 001/002, the signal between DD+ and DD- (pins 12/13 of the isolator U10 in the schematic below) cycles through the following a couple of times before the PC gives up:

The only slightly strange thing is that VDD2 of the isolator is 5V, when I think it should be 3.3V. Since that pin is only connected to a bypass capacitor & PGOOD is high this doesn't really seem to be the issue though. [Edit: Just checked on a different, working board that also uses the same USB isolator - the voltage on VDD2 is also 5V there, so I am probably just misunderstanding the datasheet)]
Conclusion
Unfortunately, I have no idea what could be going wrong, even after re-reading the datasheets a couple of times.
What am I doing wrong/how can I narrow down the root cause?
Schematic/Layout
The part of the schematic that seems relevant:

+5V/GND and +5VA/+3V3A/GNDA come from the power supplies on either side of the isolator, the downstream data lines from the hub U9 are effectively unconnected (there are some USB mux chips (FSUSB42) connected to some of them, but nothing is plugged in anywhere)
Clarification from comments:

The two sides are powered by independent power supplies, whose grounds are within 0.1V in the test setup.
The "missing" ground pins are stacked on top of the existing ones (this is how KiCAD draws symbols with many ground pins) - I double checked, and they should all be where they belong.

The layout is as follows (inner power planes hidden for clarity):

For orientation the schematic is mirrored compared to the physical layout: The reset line comes from the top right, with the USB data line below (also from the right). The data lines coming out of Hub[2] (U9) go towards the top/top left.
Part numbers

CM4: SC0674
Hubs: USB2514B-I/M2
USB Isolator: ADUM3165BRSZ-RL


Are crystal Y2 caps to wrong GND instead of GNDA? From where all the supplies come from? How are they isolated or generated?

Where are ADUM missing ground pins?

@Justme the additional ground pins are hidden below the visible ones (same as KiCAD does it for many symbols). It's a bit small, but you can also see how they are connected on the screenshot of the PCB, where only pin 14 (PGOOD) is unconnected

@Justme both grounds of Y2 are GNDA (Sorry for the confusion, I missed one when adapting the schematic for the question)

@Justme As for the power supplies: The voltages for the two sides are generated by two separate power supplies (+3V3A is subsequently generated from +5VA using an LDO). The ground potentials are within 0.5V of each other (in the current testing configuration, they are within 0.1V).

Are you aware of the fact that by using two 24MHz crystals, there will always be a tiny difference between these clocks which can cause intermodulation? Why don‘t you use one crystal and a buffer?

@StefanWyss, clock frequencies on both ends of USB partners are ALWAYS slightly different. USB framework is designed to accommodate the differences with "elasticity buffers".  And connecting clock circuits would defy the entire purpose of isolation.

Could you please post a scope trace of D- and D+ signals individually, not "between D+ and D-, with sufficient vertical scale/resolution, to understand the actual levels (with visual resolution to about 10mV) of signals relative to ground during the USB reset process? From your trace is looks like the hub receiver does not like something in chirping signals and drops the HS termination in the middle of USB_reset.

Also, did you try to test your hub via direct connection to PC, bypassing your opto-isolator?

I am afraid your USB2514B design has a serious deficiency. Pins 14 and 34 must be carefully bypassed by 0.1uF ceramic caps. Here is a snap from the manufacturer's application checklist:

Try to solder 0402 caps to these pins to ground.

Thanks, this is very interesting... The datasheet itself says "CRFILT: VDD Core Regulator Filter Capacitor: this pin can have up to a 0.1uF low-ESR capacitor to VSS, or be left unconnected." (similar for PLLFILT). I based the design on the official board from Raspberry, where they also don't include them, so I assumed they were indeed unnecessary. I guess adding them can anyway not hurt, so I will try
